# css and function hover

Tags: css

when I hover cursor on link, how change div text font color?
Is impossible then do with css?
my try:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a:hover .text {
       color:#FF00FF;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href = "">link</a>
    <div class = "text">TEXT TEXT</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your CSS definition will only affect an element inside an <a> tag with a class of 'text' rather than any element with that class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selector `a:hover .text` means: select any element with the class “text” that is [*a descendant*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) of an `A` element that has the hover state, like this:

```
<a href="">link <span class="text">TEXT TEXT</span></a>
```

But according to your markup you rather need the selector `a:hover + .text`. This means: select any element with the class “text” that is [*immediately preceded*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) by an `A` element that has the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is known as the 'next sibling' selector, and is signified by the plus symbol, thus:

```
a:hover + .text { .... }
```

However please note that the + selector does not work in Internet Explorer:
In IE6, it doesn't work at all.
IE7 and IE8 support it, but have bugs with dynamic pages, so will probably break with your hover example.
It will be fine in all other browsers, though.

Quirksmode has [a very good table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) of which browsers support which CSS features.

Answer (score 0):

If there's more than one div with `class=text` and you only want to change the first one use

`a:link ~ .text { ... }`